# Gaussian Pyramid Out of Bounds

Tags: c++, arrays, image-processing, gaussian

I am trying to write my own codes for Gaussian pyramid using c++.

I tried both reduce and expand equations as stated in http://persci.mit.edu/pub_pdfs/pyramid83.pdf, the equation (1) and (2). However, my array index is out of bounds when I am trying to access

`[2i + m][2j + n]` and `[(i - m) / 2][(j - n) / 2]`, respectively.

My Gaussian kernel: the 5x5 matrix; g1Image: the original image reduced by 1 level, both row and column are half of the dimensions of the original image's.

My `m` and `n` are set to `-2 < m/n <= 2`, thus when i access my Gaussian kernel, i add 2 to the index, becoming

```
w[m + 2][n + 2] * original_image[2i + m][2j + n]
```

I did try to set my `m` and `n` to `0 < m/n <=4` as well, equation becomes

```
w[m][n] * original_image[2i + m][2j + n] or w[m][n] * original_image[2i + m - 2][2j + n - 2]
```

Any of the mentioned equations are out of bounds.

`w[m][n] * original_image[2i][2j]` for reduce equation and 
`w[m][n] * g1Image[i / 2][j / 2]` for expand equation are working though.

However, the displayed image seems like there is no smoothing effect.

Can anyone explain to me how should I set my image dimension for each Gaussian Pyramid Reduction, Gaussian Pyramid Expansion and the m and n boundaries?

Comment: Are you sure the issue isn't coming from the fact that you're applying the kernel over your entire image dimension, and not excluding or partially convolving at the edges?

Comment: @paddy yea, you are right!! can you share more with me? what is the fastest and most easy way to do the edge handling? I try to set any negative pixel value i get to 1, but this will affect the whole image normalization especially the image pixel values after the Gaussian pyramid equation are very big.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved the problem by including this line

```
index1 = (2 * h) + m; index2 = (2 * w) + n;

if(index1  >= 0 && index1 < Height && index2 >= 0 && index2 < Width)
     temp = w[m + 2][n + 2] * original_image[index1][index2];
```

More information at :
http://www.songho.ca/dsp/convolution/convolution.html